# Windows Phone 8: XML Read issue

Tags: xml, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Okay so im looking at this xml document (http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/53.8100,-1.5500?o=xml&key=#)

Its all getting downloaded into the app correctly but i keep getting an error here

`lang = resultElements.Element("ResourceSets") _
                            .Element("ResourceSet") _
                            .Element("Resources") _
                            .Element("Location") _
                            .Element("Address") _
                            .Descendants("PostalCode").Value.ToString()`

Anybody know why?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You're trying to call `Value` on `Descendants`, which returns an IEnumerable<XElement> collection.  You need to select a single element if you're calling value on it.

Comment: Also, you could shorten your query to this:  `lang = (resultElements.Descendants("PostalCode").FirstOrDefault()).Value`; there's no need to explicitly walk through the entire document; `Descendants` will give you a collection of all the elements with that name in the document.

Comment: The Value on decendents was just a test haha but i swapped the code out for the shorter one you suggestedd and i still get a, Null Reference exception... Hmmm strange may need to come back to this tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a null reference exception is because you didn't handle the namespace in the XML document:

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
```

There's three namespaces, but two of them are assigned prefixes.  The one you want is the last one:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1"
```

The following code will do the trick:

```
Dim resultElements As XDocument = XDocument.Load("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/53.8100,-1.5500?o=xml&key=AgQtKDaecZ38rUnIbCK_gOTWrOk3a3jLScyr9dfMKD7mRmn0T0c6G9lcay1klMV3")

Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1"

Dim lang = (resultElements.Descendants(ns + "PostalCode").FirstOrDefault()).Value
```

When there is a namespace, you need to prepend the appropriate namespace to the element name - i.e., ns + "PostalCode".  The above code snippet returns "LS2 9".

`FirstOrDefault()` will return the first item that matches, or the default value if no items match.

If you expect to have a collection of postal codes, you can remove the FirstOrDefault() and then iterate through the returned collection, as well.  It would look something like this:

```
Dim lang = resultElements.Descendants(ns + "PostalCode")

For Each postalCode As XElement in lang
    Console.WriteLine(postalCode.Value)
Next
```